# Assigning different materials to different meshes on the same object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I initially had a function that created a rectangular mesh given a specific height/width:

```
void BoxMesh(float width, float height)
{
    MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mf.mesh = mesh;

    //Verticies
    Vector3[] verticies = new Vector3[4]
    {
        new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(0, height, 0), new Vector3(width, height, 0), new Vector3(width, 0, 0)
    };

    //Triangles
    int[] tri = new int[6];

    tri[0] = 0;
    tri[1] = 1;
    tri[2] = 3;

    tri[3] = 1;
    tri[4] = 2;
    tri[5] = 3;

    //normals
    
    Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[4];

    normals[0] = -Vector3.forward;
    normals[1] = -Vector3.forward;
    normals[2] = -Vector3.forward;
    normals[3] = -Vector3.forward;

    //UVs
    
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[4];
    
    uv[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
    uv[1] = new Vector2(0, 1);
    uv[2] = new Vector2(1, 1);
    uv[3] = new Vector2(1, 0);
    
    

    //initialise
    mesh.vertices = verticies;
    mesh.triangles = tri;
    mesh.normals = normals;
    mesh.uv = uv;

    //setting up collider
    polyCollider.pathCount = 1;

    Vector2[] path = new Vector2[4]
    {
        new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(0, height), new Vector2(width, height), new Vector2(width, 0)
    };

    polyCollider.SetPath(0, path);

}
```

I then decided I wanted this mesh to have an outline so I edited the function so it is now:

```
void BoxMesh(float width, float height, float OLwidth)
{
    MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mf.mesh = mesh;

    MeshFilter mfOL = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh meshOL = new Mesh();
    mfOL.mesh = meshOL;

    //Verticies
    Vector3[] verticies = new Vector3[4]
    {
        new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(0, height, 0), new Vector3(width, height, 0), new Vector3(width, 0, 0)
    };

    //Verticies Outline
    Vector3[] verticiesOL = new Vector3[4]
    {
        new Vector3(-OLwidth,-OLwidth,0), new Vector3(-OLwidth, height + OLwidth, 0), new Vector3(width + OLwidth, height + OLwidth, 0), new Vector3(width + OLwidth, -OLwidth, 0)
    };

    //Triangles
    int[] tri = new int[6];

    tri[0] = 0;
    tri[1] = 1;
    tri[2] = 3;

    tri[3] = 1;
    tri[4] = 2;
    tri[5] = 3;

    //normals
    
    Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[4];

    normals[0] = -Vector3.forward;
    normals[1] = -Vector3.forward;
    normals[2] = -Vector3.forward;
    normals[3] = -Vector3.forward;

    //UVs
    
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[4];
    
    uv[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
    uv[1] = new Vector2(0, 1);
    uv[2] = new Vector2(1, 1);
    uv[3] = new Vector2(1, 0);
    
    //initialise
    mesh.vertices = verticies;
    mesh.triangles = tri;
    mesh.normals = normals;
    mesh.uv = uv;
    
    meshOL.vertices = verticiesOL;
    meshOL.triangles = tri;
    meshOL.normals = normals;
    meshOL.uv = uv;

    //setting up collider
    polyCollider.pathCount = 1;

    Vector2[] path = new Vector2[4]
    {
        new Vector3(-OLwidth,-OLwidth,0), new Vector3(-OLwidth, height + OLwidth, 0), new Vector3(width + OLwidth, height + OLwidth, 0), new Vector3(width + OLwidth, -OLwidth, 0)
    };

    polyCollider.SetPath(0, path);

}
```

So i now have two meshes one outside the other. However I want the one on the outside to have a different material: so it looks like an outline.

[image]

I have these two materials in my mesh renderer, so how would I go about assigning one material to the outer mesh, and another to the inner mesh.

Comment: Check out the link at the Unity site on Mesh Renderers (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshRenderer.html) **NOTE**   `All the Materials used by a Mesh Renderer are held in the Materials list. Each sub-Mesh uses one Material from the Materials list. If there are more Materials assigned to the Mesh Renderer than there are sub-Meshes in the Mesh, the first sub-Mesh is rendered with each of the remaining Materials, one on top of the next.`

Comment: @jiveturkey okay so I looked into that and it makes sense, but are those meshes I created submeshes already? Or do I have to do something specific to make them submeshes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you might be missing here is "SubMesh", each submesh of a mesh will be rendered using a material from the list at a given index. 
To create a submesh you can call

```
mesh.SetTriangles(int[] triangles, int submesh);
```

You can re-use your vertexes, by specifying different faces basing on the same list of points. If you specify more submeshes than materials, remaining submeshes will be rendered solid magenta.